Differentiability for a multivariate piecewise function
Consider the function:
$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 
\frac{x^2-y^2}{x-y} , \text{ if } x \neq y \\
x^2+2x,  \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$
I want to know if this function is differentiable at (0,0) by using the definition of differentiability:
$$ \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{\Vert f(x,y) - f(0,0) - Df(0,0) (x-0,y-0)^T\Vert}{\Vert (x,y)\Vert} = 0 $$
I deduced (not sure if correctly) that $\partial_x f(0,0) = \frac{d}{dx} f(x,0) \vert_{x=0} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x,0) - f(0,0)}{x-0} = 1$ (I used 'if $x\neq y$' expression for f(x,0) and 'otherwise i.e. x=y' expression for $f(0,0)$) and $\partial_y f(0,0) = 1$ similarly but I'm not sure how to further evaluate the limit I get from using the definition i.e.:
$$ \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{\Vert f(x,y) - (x+y)\Vert}{\Vert (x,y)\Vert} $$. I guess what is really bothering me is that I donot know what expression of f(x,y) to put in. Any help would be appreciated!

Note that $x\ne y\implies f(x,y)=x+y$ and that therefore$$x\ne y\implies f(x,y)-f(0,0)-(x+y)=0.$$On the other hand, if $x=y$, then$$f(x,y)-f(0,0)-(x+y)=x^2+x+y-(x+y)=x^2.$$But then$$\frac{|f(x,y)-f(0,0)-(x+y)|}{\|(x,y)\|}=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}0&\text{ if }x\ne y\\\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}(\leqslant|x|)&\text{ if }x=y\end{array}\right.$$and therefore$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{|f(x,y)-f(0,0)-(x+y)|}{\|(x,y)\|}=0.$$

I see, thanks! idnt realize we could consider both cases separately and show they both lead to the same conclusion. As a follow up, what would the conclusion be if hypothetically $x \neq y$ leads to limit zero but for $x=y$, the limit is non-zero. Then is the function not differentiable everywhere or only considered differentiable when $x \neq y$?

If the limit when $x=y$ was not $0$, then $f$ would not be differentiable at $(0,0)$. But if $f(x,y)=x+y$ when $x\ne y$, then $f$ would be differentiable at every point $(a,b)$ with $a\ne b$.
